# Postgresql VARCHAR column formatting a UNIQUElDENTIFIER value coming from a SQL Server column

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

There is a transfer happening between two database.
The first one is a SQL Server. The second one is Postgresql.

I have a column that has a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER in SQL Server and it is sending data to a VARCHAR column in Postgresql. The way the code is implemented expects that column to be a varchar/string.

The issue is that the data gets transferred to that column, but has some formatting issues.

```
The SQL Server UNIQUEIDENTIFIER value:  27E66FD9-79B8-4342-92A9-3CA87E497E69
The Postgresql VARCHAR value:           b'27E66FD9-79B8-4342-92A9-3CA87E497E69'
```

Obviously, I don't want the extra b'' in there. Is there a way to change this in the database without modifying the data type?

Comment: `select substring(colname, 3, 36) from your_table;`  If you have `uuid-ossp` installed, then you can `select substring(colname, 3, 36)::uuid from your table;`

Comment: Some more information on how this transfer is being done would be helpful. Though at a guess I going to say at some point it is passing through Python(the b'...'). Is the  entire `b'...'` string actually showing up in the Postgres column?